# Multiple Volume mounts with Kubernetes: one works, one doesn't

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-storage

I am trying to create a Kubernetes pod with a single container which has two external volumes mounted on it. My .yml pod file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-project
  labels:
    name: my-project
spec:
  containers:
    - image: my-username/my-project
      name: my-project
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: nginx-http
        - containerPort: 443
          name: nginx-ssl-https
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/projects/my-project/media/upload
          name: pd-data
        - mountPath: /home/projects/my-project/backups
          name: pd2-data
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: vpregistrykey
  volumes:
    - name: pd-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pd-claim
    - name: pd2-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pd2-claim
```

I am using Persistent Volumes and Persisten Volume Claims, as such:
`PV`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pd-disk
  labels:
    name: pd-disk
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 250Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: "pd-disk"
    fsType: "ext4"
```

`PVC`

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pd-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 250Gi
```

I have initially created my disks using the command:
`$ gcloud compute disks create --size 250GB pd-disk`
Same goes for the second disk and second PV and PVC. Everything seems to work ok when I create the pod, no errors are thrown. Now comes the weird part: one of the paths is being mounted correctly (and is therefor persistent) and the other one is being erased every time I restart the pod...

I have tried re-creating everything from scratch, but nothing changes. Also, from the pod description, both volumes seem to be correctly mounted:

```
$ kubectl describe pod my-project
Name:       my-project
...
Volumes:
  pd-data:
    Type: PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pd-claim
    ReadOnly: false
  pd2-data:
    Type: PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pd2-claim
    ReadOnly: false
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What version of kubernetes do you use and how did you restart the pod?

Comment: I am using Kubernetes v1, and for restarting the pod I am using `kubectl delete -f my-project.yml` followed by `kubectl create -f my-project.yml`

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl version`?

Comment: `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.4", GitCommit:"a5949fea3a91d6a50f40a5684e05879080a4c61d", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.7", GitCommit:"e4e6878293a339e4087dae684647c9e53f1cf9f0", GitTreeState:"clean"}`

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post self-answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue.

Comment: Sorry to let you down, but I was unable to find a solution last year, so I just found an alternative which involved a single volume being mounted...

Comment: Are you sure that your PVCs got actually bound to the correct PVs? Because since you are doing manual provisioning, you should first specify the `claimRef` on the PV object, which points to your PVC, and then create the PVC with that name. I do not see `claimRef` in your examples, neither the full resources for reproducing it (seconds claim and disk). If you apply the PVC example you have as-is, it will get dynamically provisioned by the default storage class, which is not the bahavior you expect (since you create your disk manually via `gcloud` command)

Answer (score 5):

The Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) states:

> Volumes can not mount onto other volumes or have hard links to other
>   volumes

I had the same issue and in my case the problem was that both volume mounts had overlapping mountPaths, i.e. both started with /var/.

They mounted without issues after fixing that.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see any direct problem for which such behavior as explained above has occurred! But what I can rather ask you to try is to use a "Deployment" instead of a "Pod" as suggested by many [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325087/in-kubernetes-what-is-the-difference-between-a-pod-and-a-deployment), especially when using PVs and PVCs. [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#use-case) takes care of many things to maintain the "Desired State".  I have attached my code below for your reference which works and both the volumes are persistent even after deleting/terminating/restarting as this is managed by the Deployment's desired state.

Two difference which you would find in my code from yours are:

1. I have a deployment object instead of pod
2. I am using GlusterFs for my volume.

Deployment yml.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: platform
  labels:
    component: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: nginx
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        role: app-1
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: vip-intOAM:5001/nginx:1.15.3
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/etc/nginx/conf.d/"
            name: nginx-confd
          - mountPath: "/var/www/"
            name: nginx-web-content
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-confd
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: glusterfsvol-nginx-confd-pvc
      - name: nginx-web-content
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: glusterfsvol-nginx-web-content-pvc
```

One of my PV

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: glusterfsvol-nginx-confd-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  glusterfs:
    endpoints: gluster-cluster
    path: nginx-confd
    readOnly: false
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  claimRef:
    name: glusterfsvol-nginx-confd-pvc
    namespace: platform
```

PVC for the above

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: glusterfsvol-nginx-confd-pvc
  namespace: platform
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the `volumeHandle` in the two PVs are same, which will make it fail to mount both PVs into same pod.