# How to create an environment variable in kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to pass an environment variable in kubernetes container.

**What have I done so far ?**

- Create a deployment

  `kubectl create deployment foo --image=foo:v1`
- Create a NODEPORT service and expose the port

  `kubectl expose deployment/foo --type=NodePort --port=9000`
- See the pods

  `kubectl get pods`
- dump the configurations (so to add the environment variable)

  `kubectl get deployments -o yaml > dev/deployment.yaml`

  `kubectl get svc -o yaml > dev/services.yaml`

  `kubectl get pods -o yaml > dev/pods.yaml`
- Add env variable to the pods
  env:

  - name: FOO_KEY
    value: "Hellooooo"
- Delete the svc,pods,deployments

  `kubectl delete -f dev/ --recursive`
- Apply the configuration

  `kubectl apply -f dev/ --recursive`
- Verify env parameters

  `kubectl describe pods`

**Something weird**

If I manually changed the meta information of the pod yaml and hard code the name of the pod. It gets the env variable. However, this time two pods come up one with the hard coded name and other with the hash with it. For example, if the name I hardcoded was "foo", two pods namely foo and foo-12314faf (example) would appear in "kubectl get pods". Can you explain why ?

**Question**

Why does the verification step does not show the environment variable ?

Comment: Hi, Could you verify the variable inside the deployment yaml?

Comment: you should mutate deployment, it's not good idea to directly mutate pods if is created by deployment

Comment: `kubectl get deploy foo -o yaml` will be the command

Comment: I added the env variable inside pod yaml file. I didn't know if they can be passed in the deployment as well. Is it ?

Comment: and No. The variable is not present in the output of the command you wrote.

Comment: btw `env` will come under containers,  not in pod. where exactly are you adding the environment variable ?

Comment: I saw that env can also be given under kind: Pod as well. Anyways, declaring the env in the deployment yaml works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: podSpec is composed by replicaSet which is also composed by deployment.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation that says it can be inside the pod section too https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#use-configmap-defined-environment-variables-in-pod-commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the issue is resolved in the comment section.

If you want to set **env** to pods I would suggust you to use **set** sub commend

`kubectl set env --help`  will provide more detail such as list the env and create new one

```
Examples:
  # Update deployment 'registry' with a new environment variable
  kubectl set env deployment/registry STORAGE_DIR=/local

  # List the environment variables defined on a deployments 'sample-build'
  kubectl set env deployment/sample-build --list
```

Deployment enables declarative updates for Pods and ReplicaSets. Pods are not typically directly launched on a cluster. Instead, pods are usually managed by replicaSet which is managed by deployment.

following thread discuss [what-is-the-difference-between-a-pod-and-a-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325087/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pod-and-a-deployment)

Comment: Can you also clarify why was the env variable not working when it was added to the pod spec directly ? I have added details about this in my question. Please acknowledge that too.

Comment: I do not know what exactly, you are trying. nevertheless, I updated my answer with more description to list, add or delete the env variable on deployment.

Comment: I guess I didn't k8s much back then. Now the question I asked sounds funny. Accepting it now 

Answer (score 2):

1. You can add any number of env vars into your deployment file

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: lord/auth
          env:
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: "mongodb://auth-mongo-srv:27017/auth"
```

```
 process.env.MONGO_URI
```

or you can add a secret first then use newly created secret into your countless deployment files to share same environment variable with value:

```
kubectl create secret generic jwt-secret --from-literal=JWT_KEY=my_awesome_jwt_secret_code
```

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: lord/auth
          env:
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: "mongodb://auth-mongo-srv:27017/auth"
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
```

```
 process.env.MONGO_URI
 process.env.JWT_KEY
```